# Command prompt disappears with cx_freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I am brand new to using cx_freeze for compiling Python files.  I am trying to compile my program into an exe, and I need two txt files to go along with it.  I am using this as my setup.py code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includesfiles = ['textone.txt', 'texttwo.txt']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = []

setup(
    name = "Program",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A fun game.",
    author = "author",
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includesfiles}},
executables = [Executable('program.py')]
)
```

When I run `setup.py buld` from cmd, and then run the program that it gives me, the command prompt window briefly opens then closes before I can read any text on it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `setup.py` looks correct. What happens in the code you're trying to convert? Does it want some command line arguments (that happened to me recently)?

Comment: The executable is probably having some sort of error, but Windows closes the command prompt before you can see it. Start a command prompt yourself and run the executable from there to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like it should work. What is the code you're trying to convert to exe?