# cx_freeze executable quickly opens and closes without doing what the script is supposed to do

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-3.4

First off, I am brand new to programming, python, and this forum so sorry for any mistakes.

I wrote a python script but want to be able to run it on a computer without python installed, so I did some research and found I would need to download a program in order to convert py to exe.  cx_freeze was the only one that supported python 3.4.

I followed the instructions in a popular YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHcDHSWRCRQ) but when I double click the exe, the command box pops open for a split second and then closes.  There is some text but it goes too quickly for me to read it.

It looks like these threads are about the same problem but they went unanswered.  Any ideas?

[Command prompt disappears with cx_freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472973/command-prompt-disappears-with-cx-freeze)

[cx_Freeze exe file opens for a second then closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000282/cx-freeze-exe-file-opens-for-a-second-then-closes)

Thanks!

Edit:  If it helps, here is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
name = "Teacher Pages Search" ,
version = "1" ,
description = "By Gambiteer" , executables = [Executable("Teacher Pages Search.py")] ,
)
```

Here is Teacher Pages Search.py

```
import urllib.request
import html.parser
import webbrowser

class MyHTMLParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(False)
        self.teacherLink = False
        self.url = ""

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for combo in attrs:
                if "sw-directory-item" in combo[1]:
                    self.teacherLink = True
                if self.teacherLink is True:
                    if "http:" in combo[1]:
                        self.url = combo[1]


    def handle_data(self, data):
        data = data.lower()
        data = data.replace("'","")
        data = data.replace("\\","")
        data = data.replace(" ","")
        if self.teacherLink is True:
            for teacher in teacherList:
                if teacher in data:
                    webbrowser.open(self.url)
        self.teacherLink = False


teacherListInput = input("Enter the last name of your teachers, without punctuation, separated by commas:\n")
teacherListInput = teacherListInput.replace(" ","")
teacherList = list()
while teacherListInput.find(',') != -1:
    commaLoc = teacherListInput.find(',')
    teacherName = teacherListInput[0:commaLoc]
    teacherList.append(teacherName)
    teacherListInput = teacherListInput[commaLoc+1:]
teacherList.append(teacherListInput)

f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.scarsdaleschools.k12.ny.us/site/Default.aspx?PageType=1&SiteID=65&ChannelID=94&DirectoryType=6")
webpage = f.read()
parser = MyHTMLParser()
html_parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = html_parser.unescape(str(webpage))
parser.feed(unescaped)

input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: You can run you exe file using .bat file. Create new bat file, insert into it `TeacherPagesSearch.exe 2>log.txt` rename you exe to `TeacherPagesSearch.exe` and run bat file. Then copy error from log.txt to you post.

Comment: Alternatively, run the exe from a command prompt, which should mean that the error stays around long enough to be read.

Comment: @ThomasK I've followed all the above mentioned steps. but i'm getting Importerror "No module named queue" and "No module named urllib3". How to resolve this ?? After installing urllib3 module i didn't get that error but when i tried to install queue it showed "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement."